# Audit log in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, audit-trail, audit-logging

We have microservice architecture application in spring boot. We are planning to add an audit logs to our services. So that we can get the information like,

- Admin123 deactivated User123
- User123 changed the password
- User123 logged in

High level:

1. For this we are planning to write the required info into a log file as a JSON format. (Each service logs will be maintained separately)
2. Then Devops team, uses Filebeat to read and pushes the logs to elastic search.
3. And then we can query/visualize the information from elastic search  using kibana.

JSON (log structure):

```
{
    "userId"        : "100",
    "ip"            : "192.168.1.1",
    "deviceId"      : "f07a13984f6d116a",
    "country"       : "India",
    "language"      : "English (U.S)"
    "userAgent"     : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
    "timestamp"     : "2004-02-12T15:19:21.000+00:00",
    "event"         : "update product",
    "resource"      : "user",
    "action"        : "deactivate",
    "objectId"      : "22",
    "objectType"    : "user",
    "description"   : "Deactivated user",
    "service"       : "User service",
    "appVersion"    : "v1",
    "requestId"     : "db176f6b-b4c6-4a59-ac62-4d471eedf354"
    "server"        : "i0e5b5c88",
    "serverLocation": "us-east-1",
    "protocol"      : "https",
    "method"        : "PATCH",
    "statusCode"    : "200"
}
```

Can anyone suggest better **architecture** to achieve custom audit logs using spring boot?

So that I can extract the useful information out of it.

Comment: in what ways better? It's not really clear what you want and what is the problem with the thing you're now proposing

Comment: The question is candidate to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @eis Elaborated my question.

Comment: Are you going to write into file using Log4j or file utility?

Comment: @AlexpandiyanChokkan To be frank, i'm yet to decide on, any audit library is available. I just saw Log4j supports audit logs. Any suggestion here?

Comment: If you want to write in a file with the above mentioned fields, you should go for utility function. If you go with `Log4j` everything will be in the message field. Can split it with the help of `Logstash`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexpandiyanChokkan. Any advise in architectural part?.